# Can Blender Animate armature automatically..?

Tags: python, armature

I'm trying to find a script, add-on, python, AI, whatever in order to have blender key frame an armature on its own. You know how, pretty much any video game has enemies controlled by a bot, CPU or whatever the technical term is? That's the same concept I'm looking to achieve, except in blender render, not BGE.

What I mean by that is this: Id like too Email to myself the keyframes I want set for my armatures locRotScale, copy paste it to a blender script/python, & blender inputs it automatically to the timeline, dope sheet, nla, you name it.

I've been racking my mind & researching for days to no avail. I've never created a python for blender, but if I could I would for this. To be honest im newly wed & would love spending more time with my wife. If there's a way I can be with her separate from blender AND still have animation made automatically, of course I'll take advantage of both opportunities.

Comment: Are you looking for information about motion capture data like Mixamo? https://www.mixamo.com/#/?page=1&type=Motion%2CMotionPack

Comment: I've done bvh exports before. But the trouble is the armature gets deformed when exporting. Like I use rigify, and the spine bone gets removed entirely. I'll look into mixamo